# Extracting all text before first tab from a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, split

So I have this text_data from http://www.manythings.org/anki/
it looks like this

```
['Hi.\tHallo!\tCC-BY 2.0 (France) Attribution: tatoeba.org #538123 (CM) & #380701 (cburgmer)\n',
 'Hi.\tGrüß Gott!\tCC-BY 2.0 (France) Attribution: tatoeba.org #538123 (CM) & #659813 (Esperantostern)\n',
 'Run!\tLauf!\tCC-BY 2.0 (France) Attribution: tatoeba.org #906328 (papabear) & #941078 (Fingerhut)\n',
 'Wow!\tPotzdonner!\tCC-BY 2.0 (France) Attribution: tatoeba.org #52027 (Zifre) & #2122382 (Pfirsichbaeumchen)\n',
 'Wow!\tDonnerwetter!\tCC-BY 2.0 (France) Attribution: tatoeba.org #52027 (Zifre) & #2122391 (Pfirsichbaeumchen)\n',
 'Fire!\tFeuer!\tCC-BY 2.0 (France) Attribution: tatoeba.org #1829639 (Spamster) & #1958697 (Tamy)\n',
 'Help!\tHilfe!\tCC-BY 2.0 (France) Attribution: tatoeba.org #435084 (lukaszpp) & #575889 (MUIRIEL)\n',
...
]
```

I did this

```
English = []
for sent in data_examples:
    pattern  = re.compile(r'.+?\t')
    matches = pattern.finditer(sent)
    for match in matches:
        English.append(match)
```

how to capture the English in the texts? Mine isnt really working.

Comment: First, you could move the `pattern=...` outside of the loop since it is not changing.

Comment: *mine isn't really working* - is not a detailed problem statement... Why do you use `finditer` if you just want the first word? Why not `pattern.match(sent)`?

Comment: There is no english in your example.

Comment: BTW, why Tatoeba? Do you think you can trust these corpora? They look to be user-contributed, without proper localization quality assurance done.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I am pretty new, I was check on youtube and people use finditer, i guess Tomerikoo making a good point using match. And I am working on it for learning, quality isn't prime consideration for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your English segments are located in the first column.

All you need to do is

```
English = [sent.split('\t')[0] for sent in data_examples]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** 
This might solve your purpose

```
import nltk
words = None
try:
    words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words())
except:
    nltk.download('words')
    words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words())

# Extra words which are not present in nltk words corpus
words_need_to_include = ['france']

for w in words_need_to_include:
    words.add(w)

# Words which we don't want in nltk words corpus
words_need_to_exclude = ['by']

for w in words_need_to_exclude:
    words.remove(w)

# Input data
in_text = ['Hi.\tHallo!\tCC-BY 2.0 (France) Attribution: tatoeba.org #538123 (CM) & #380701 (cburgmer)\n france',
 'Hi.\tGrüß Gott!\tCC-BY 2.0 (France) Attribution: tatoeba.org #538123 (CM) & #659813 (Esperantostern)\n',
 'Run!\tLauf!\tCC-BY 2.0 (France) Attribution: tatoeba.org #906328 (papabear) & #941078 (Fingerhut)\n',
 'Wow!\tPotzdonner!\tCC-BY 2.0 (France) Attribution: tatoeba.org #52027 (Zifre) & #2122382 (Pfirsichbaeumchen)\n',
 'Wow!\tDonnerwetter!\tCC-BY 2.0 (France) Attribution: tatoeba.org #52027 (Zifre) & #2122391 (Pfirsichbaeumchen)\n',
 'Fire!\tFeuer!\tCC-BY 2.0 (France) Attribution: tatoeba.org #1829639 (Spamster) & #1958697 (Tamy)\n',
 'Help!\tHilfe!\tCC-BY 2.0 (France) Attribution: tatoeba.org #435084 (lukaszpp) & #575889 (MUIRIEL)\n',
]

# Code
English = []
for x in in_text:
    English.append(" ".join(w for w in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(x) if w.lower() in words))
    #print(" ".join(nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(x)))

print(English)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
['Hi France Attribution france', 'Hi France Attribution', 'Run France Attribution', 'Wow France Attribution', 'Wow France Attribution', 'Fire France Attribution', 'Help France Attribution']
```

Comment: Also added variable to exclude words from the string which are not required but are part of English language